# Unix code wanted to change column values

Tags: bash, unix

I have a file that looks like this:

```
ID1 ID2 3
ID2 ID3 3
ID4 ID5 3
ID6 ID7 4
ID8 ID9 4
ID8 ID6 4
```

And I want to change it to:

```
ID1 ID2 1
ID2 ID3 1
ID4 ID5 1
ID6 ID7 2
ID8 ID9 2
ID8 ID6 2
```

So I want to change all 3's and 4's from the third column to 1's and 2's respectively. What is the most efficient way to do this for a very large file? Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
awk '{ $3 -= 2; print }' filename >new_filename
```

Or, if you really only want to touch 3's and 4's:

```
awk '{ if ( $3 == 3 ) { $3 = 1 } else if ( $3 == 4 ) { $3 = 2 }; print}' filename >new_filename
```

Comment: for the 2nd case, can shorten it a bit: `awk '$3==3||$3==4 {$3-=2} {print}'`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming third column is always the last one:

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]\)3$/\11/;s/\([^0-9]\)4$/\12/'
```